# Can 'grep' be used in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, grep, nvidia

I've been trying to use `grep` to delete all of files containing the string "`nividia`" using Ansible. No matter what I try I keep on getting errors. Is this even possible?

```yaml
---
- name: Delete nvidia
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
   - name: delete nvidia files
  ignore_errors: yes
  file:
    state: absent
    path:
    job: grep -lRZ nvidia . | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`file` module – Manage files and file properties - Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameters) there is no such thing like `job`.

> *Can 'grep' be used in Ansible playbook?*

Yes, of course.

To execute native commands piped together you may use the [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html).

In your case and because of the nature of the task (force remove of an somehow "unvalidated" input), it is not recommended to use this approach. The recommended way in Ansible is instead to use certain specific modules and a chain of tasks to achieve your goal.

```yaml
- name: Delete Nvidia files
  shell:
    cmd: grep -lRZ nvidia {{ FULLPATH }} | xargs -0 rm -f
  vars:
    FULLPATH: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
```

Since Ansible will execute the task via an own shell and environment you will need to use a full path to find your files and for deletion. You could also [setting the remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it, this makes so much sense! (and it worked!)